# Why is this code printing different numbers even when the input is same?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this:
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/888/A

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a, i, q, count;

    scanf("%d ", &q);

    int ar[q];

    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &ar[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        if (i != q - 1 && i != 0)
        {
            if (((ar[i] < ar[i + 1]) && (ar[i] < ar[i - 1])))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if (((ar[i] > ar[i + 1]) && (ar[i] > ar[i - 1])))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the program with the first test case, it prints random numbers.
When I run it again, it prints DIFFERENT random numbers.

I looked up the solution: 
https://github.com/Waqar-107/Codeforces/blob/master/A-set/888A.Local%20Extrema.py

Isn't that code exactly what I wrote ? Why is my code printing strange things ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is probably because you have a bug. Take a debugger and check your program (or mentally go over the algorithm, using pen and paper.)

Comment: You never initialize `count`.

Comment: Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value which will seem almost random. Depending on type and the seemingly random value, using it might even lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11962457)

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Thanks, It's fine now.

Comment: Older versions of c do not necessarily support initializing arrays using a variable as the length. Try making sure your compiler supports and is set up to compile with a modern standard, or set the length of your array using a literal. The max length of the data is usually stated on codeforces so you can use that.

Comment: What is `a`, `q`, and `ar`?  If you are using a variable for something more than a simple index, you should name them something representative.

Comment: ..and, as @PaulOgilvie comments above, use your debugger!  Had you done so, the effect of the uninitialized 'count' would have been immediately obvious, you would not have needed this question and would have got your code working earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the variable `count` to zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
int a, i, q, count=0;

scanf("%d ", &q);

int ar[q];

for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    scanf("%d ", &ar[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    if (i != q - 1 && i != 0)
    {
        if (((ar[i] < ar[i + 1]) && (ar[i] < ar[i - 1])))
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if (((ar[i] > ar[i + 1]) && (ar[i] > ar[i - 1])))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", count);
return 0;
}
```